# Can I generate a Trello card from a template via URL?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Is there a URL I can create that will take a Trello Card I use as a template and populate its contents based on the URL (an URL wherein I could manipulate the parameters for to generate the desired out comes)? If so, can I then... using the same URL have that "now populated" card moved to a specific board > list?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a kind of REST style URL that you can manipulate the parameters? Or are you asking if there is a way to add information from the current web page as a Trello card?

Comment: @xtoq I edited the question for claritys sake.

Comment: In that case, @Alex V's suggestions are your best bet. Just keep in mind that neither Zapier or IFTTT are triggered by adding a label, and neither of them can move cards, only create/duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You have three options, depending on what's your role and need (your question itself touches different technical areas, not a single one):

1. As a casual user: **email stuff to board**, which will automatically create cards (you can't template much of it like no checklists, but you easily control on which board a card appears). I use it for "Inbox" boards to stack cards to review later.
2. As an advanced user: **deploy a recipe in IFTTT or zap in Zapier** or any other similar paid/free automation service to create cards on boards: **you can both template cards (including lables, checklists, dates, members, attachments) and choose boards**. If you need manipulations with URLs and webhooks, this scenario supports it too.
3. As a developer: use option 2 above as a shortcut to save time and effort, or to build an app based on Trello's API.

At my company I decided to use zaps (option 2) for most repetitive tasks (cards created on boards from all kinds of sources) and allow users focus on actual work with cards. I only lack a way to automate moving cards between boards.

Comment: Couldn't you use IFTTT to automate moving cards based on a tag/label?

Comment: IFTTT can't move cards, only create them. It also only triggers when a card is added to a board or list, or when a card is assigned to the account connected with IFTTT.

Zapier also can only create - not move - cards, and is not triggered by adding a label to a card; the closest option is a trigger for any new activity.

The options Alex V provided are the only ones I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider, the bookmarklet generator at: https://trello.com/en-GB/add-card

Currently, the bookmarklet sends you to a link a bit like this:

`https://trello.com/en-GB/add-card?name={card_name}&idList={list_id}&url={url}`

If you can control the content of `url` you can probably control what ends up on the card.